# MySQL get all the months of the year data

Tags: mysql

I need to get all stats of the months but some months dont have records in the table.

```sql
SELECT `nationality` AS `nationality`,
MONTHNAME((booked_date)) AS `MonthName`,
COUNT(*) AS `dataCount`, 
MONTH(booked_date) AS `MonthNumber`, 
YEAR(booked_date) AS `YearNumber`,
SUM(amount) AS `amount`
FROM bookings
WHERE YEAR(booked_date) = '2023'
AND MONTH(booked_date) = '1'
GROUP BY `MonthName`,`nationality` 
ORDER BY `dataCount` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

that what i have tried but i get only the selected month, i need to get all records of the year even if the month is not existed in table

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthYear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `booked_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booked_date` date NOT NULL,
  `booked_on` date NOT NULL,
  `booking_ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: You can't select a row if it doesn't exist, obviously. You therefore require a list of months to join with - either generate a sequence, a stored list in a table or utilise a *calendar table*, often a must-have for reporting purposes.

Comment: Could you provide the `CREATE TABLE` of `bookings`

Answer (score 2):

Using the schema you provided:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthYear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `booked_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booked_date` date NOT NULL,
  `booked_on` date NOT NULL,
  `booking_ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

You can use a CTE (common table expression) to build your list of months, and then `LEFT JOIN` onto those months:

```sql
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT 1 AS month_number, 'January' AS month_name UNION SELECT 2, 'February' UNION SELECT 3, 'March' UNION SELECT 4, 'April' UNION SELECT 5, 'May' UNION SELECT 6, 'June' UNION SELECT 7, 'July' UNION SELECT 8, 'August' UNION SELECT 9, 'September' UNION SELECT 10, 'October' UNION SELECT 11, 'November' UNION SELECT 12, 'December'
)

SELECT
    calendar.month_name,
    calendar.month_number,
    nationality,
    COUNT(bookings.booking_id) AS totalBookings,
    SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM
    calendar
    LEFT JOIN bookings ON calendar.month_number = MONTH(bookings.booked_date)
        AND YEAR(bookings.booked_date) = '2023'
GROUP BY
    calendar.month_name,
    nationality
ORDER BY
    calendar.month_number ASC
```

Output would look something like:

```
month_name   | month_number | nationality | totalBookings | amount 
------------ | ------------ | ----------- | ------------- | --------
January      | 1            | USA         | 50            | 5000
February     | 2            | Canada      | 40            | 4000
March        | 3            | USA         | 30            | 3000
April        | 4            | UK          | 20            | 2000
May          | 5            | USA         | 10            | 1000
June         | 6            | Canada      | 0             | 0
July         | 7            | USA         | 0             | 0
August       | 8            | UK          | 0             | 0
September    | 9            | USA         | 0             | 0
October      | 10           | Canada      | 0             | 0
November     | 11           | USA         | 0             | 0
December     | 12           | UK          | 0             | 0
```

Comment: Table 'bookings' doesn't exist in engine #error @zanderwar

Comment: Provide the schema for your table

Comment: do you have anydesk or teamviewer? i think it will be easy for you to understand if you can see the schema by your self

Comment: Sorry, you shouldn't let strangers onto your system. I am merely asking for you to copy/paste the `CREATE TABLE` schema; that you can obtain by exporting the table to SQL,  into your question... even if you would like to remove columns that are irrelevant to your question

Comment: @zenderwar okay, already added to the question

Comment: I would add monthnumber to the CTE, and compare like: `calendar.month_number = MONTH(bookings.booked_date)`, just because I always type the name of the month wrong ("January" vs. "januari" )

Comment: I updated the SQL and tested it locally for you using the schema you provided in your question. If you get a table does not exist error, then the table doesn't exist and you're likely on the wrong database

Comment: @Luuk I updated it to include your recommendation, nice one!

Comment: @zanderwar #1932 - Table 'project0001.bookings' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: The SQL in this answer has been tested and is working fine against your schema. My bet is that `bookings` does not exist in the `project0001` database; because SQL engines do not typically give ambiguous errors at least in the regard of whether or not a table exists.

Comment: @zanderwar can you check this question pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75364880/need-a-little-push-with-some-query-details