# need a little push with some query details

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have two tables "users" and "bookings"

and i need to count how many users have entered and registered by selected year and every month

and how many amount they have spent for the matched year and month

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_nationality` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_birthYear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_passportNumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_hotel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `addedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `user_nationality`, `user_birthYear`, `user_email`, `user_passportNumber`, `user_hotel`, `gender`, `addedOn`) VALUES
(104, 'john abraham', 'albania', 1994, 'john@john.com', '11100', 'google', 'male', '2023-01-29 09:06:41'),
(112, 'jah graz', 'morocco', 1990, 'jah@hah.com', '1843', 'df', 'male', '2023-02-06 17:29:58'),
(115, 'ronaldo abraham', 'angola', 1993, 'ronaldo@gmail.com', '87565', 'ng', 'male', '2023-02-06 17:30:42'),
(116, 'zhengjian yangben', 'china', 1983, 'gfjhfghfgh@ytfghj.com', 'e00000000', 'gt', 'female', '2023-02-06 17:30:56'),
(117, 'oksiao tiah', 'china', 1983, 'oksia@ytfghj.com', 'e000000001', 'google', 'female', '2023-02-06 17:31:26');
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_birthYear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_nationality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_group` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `place_id` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `booked_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `booked_date` date NOT NULL,
  `booked_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `booking_ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isDomestic` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `bookings` (`booking_id`, `user_name`, `user_birthYear`, `user_nationality`, `user_id`, `user_group`, `place_id`, `booked_by`, `booked_date`, `booked_on`, `booking_ref`, `amount`, `status`, `isDomestic`) VALUES
(647, 'john abraham', 1994, 'albania', 104, 'adult', '36', 4, '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02 14:38:42', 'B-12167534871964719944', '200.00', 0, 'false'),
(648, 'zhengjian yangben', 1983, 'china', 116, 'adult', '36', 4, '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02 14:41:12', 'B-83167534874736719834', '300.00', 0, 'false'),
(649, 'zhengjian yangben', 1983, 'china', 104, 'adult', '37', 4, '2023-02-06', '2023-02-03 19:50:43', 'B-41167566360101919834', '100.00', 0, 'false'),
(650, 'john abraham', 1994, 'albania', 104, 'adult', '37', 4, '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06 06:07:03', 'B-41167566360101919834', '0.00', 0, 'false'),
(651, 'john abraham', 1994, 'albania', 116, 'adult', '37', 4, '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06 06:07:44', 'B-54167566365174419944', '0.00', 0, 'false'),
(652, 'zhengjian yangben', 1983, 'china', 116, 'adult', '37', 4, '2023-02-06', '2023-02-06 06:07:44', 'B-54167566365174419944', '0.00', 0, 'false'),
(653, 'john abraham', 1994, 'albania', 104, 'adult', '36', 4, '2023-02-02', '2023-02-02 14:38:42', 'B-12167534871964719944', '200.00', 0, 'false'),
(654, 'john abraham', 1994, 'albania', 104, 'adult', '36', 4, '2023-02-02', '2023-01-01 14:38:42', 'B-12167534871964719944', '200.00', 0, 'false');
```

here is what i have tried

first:

```sql
SELECT
`user_nationality` AS `Nationality`,
COUNT(`user_id`) AS `usersCount`,
MONTHNAME(`addedOn`) AS `monthName`,
MONTH(`addedOn`) AS `month`
FROM `users`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`addedOn`,'2023-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(`addedOn`,'2023-%m')
GROUP BY `monthName`,`Nationality`
ORDER BY `month`
```

from above code i can get the correct results, but i cant get the correct amount if i join bookings table

i need to join bookings table to get total amount for the matched country, year and month

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jGKpW5DbqsNxp3KixatSBn/0 if anybody needs a working example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer specifically, instead, generically to help others. Follow this as a guide and translate this into what you need for your specific use case. But... before I get into the details. You are missing Primary Keys and Foreign Keys from the data model you have provided. Get your basics right.

Looks like you are working with some kind of hotel booking system. Imagine the scenario... you turn up at a hotel in real life, tell the receptionist you have a booking, they ask you your name, and you don't tell them.... You won't be passing reception. You data model is no different. Get the basics right and the rest falls into place.

Anyhow, you need something like this;

```
SELECT
    main_table.id
    , SUM(second_table.field_you_want_to_sum)
    , MONTH(second_table.created_date)
    , YEAR(second_table.created_date)
    , CONCAT(YEAR(second_table.created_date), "-", MONTH(second_table.created_Date))
FROM
    main_table
    LEFT JOIN second_table ON main_table.id = second_table.main_table_id_fk
GROUP BY 
    main_table.id, CONCAT(YEAR(second_table.created_date), "-", MONTH(second_table.created_date))
;
```

SUM / COUNT, etc. Same concept in this context. You'll also probably want an ORDER BY in there too, hence why the CONCAT party is erring towards the yyyy-mm-dd format as this is how you need to structure things.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: hi @Michael Cropper, your query didn't help, please check this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jGKpW5DbqsNxp3KixatSBn/2 and you will see userCount we have "2" from china but if i join bookings table https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jGKpW5DbqsNxp3KixatSBn/5 you will see userCount from china "4" and i need to get the first result which is "2"

Comment: Check my updated answer - the screenshot at the bottom. I tried the same thing in DB Fiddle and it struggled, so spun up a DB, inserted the data you had and tweaked the query you had and the results returned fine. Is that the data you're expecting to see? Quick glance it appears to be anyhow.